# Website response time: Difference between `Load` and `Finish`

Tags: html, google-chrome, time, google-chrome-devtools, response

I needed to check a webpage's response time, so I visited the site on Chrome, opened Devtools and switched to the <kbd>Network</kbd> tab to check the response time:

[image]

As you can see, there are two times: The first one is `Finish` and the second one is `Load`.

I think `Finish` is the time taken to load the whole page with all the resources including delays, but what is `Load`? I thought if I add all these times together I would get the time for `Load` but this isn't the case.

What would be considered the response time of this website, `Load` or `Finish`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `Finish` time in Chrome Devtools includes the asynchronously loading (non blocking) objects/elements on the page which may continue downloading way after the `onLoad` event for the page has fired.

The response time for a website generally means the `Load` time, because that is user perceivable, and at this point user can see that the browser has finished loading and page is ready on their screen.

The `Finish` time, although technically also a response time, doesn't have as much end-user implication.

In some cases, it seems that the `Finish` timer never stops but continues increasing, so it may not be the best assessment of web page response time.

Comment: It's not quite right to say that the finish time "doesn't have as much end-user implication". For example the page could have loaded all its elements but show a spinner because it is waiting on data back from request. The page has "loaded" but from the user's view isn't "finished" and is definitely not usable.

Comment: You are technically correct, if requests are flying back and forth between browser and various endpoints, page isn't done. Current web design is firmly in category; there are always outstanding requests and pages continually exchanging data. 'Page load' has lost meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the difference between the load time and the finish time is that **load time loads the elements whatever needed to load the web content on the page**, but the **finish time is that it will try to access all the ajax calls needed(Dynamic content loading while being on the same page)**. Considering the finish time as response time is not good. To calculate the response time we need to consider the load time, Because i am currently working on the page loading issue itself.

Answer (score -4):

DevTools displays the timing of the DOMContentLoaded and load events in multiple places on the Network panel. The DOMContentLoaded event is colored blue, and the load event is red.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/unni3.png

Comment: He didn't ask about DomContentLoaded, but instead did ask for Finish, which you haven't addressed.

Comment: Information provided is not what is asked