# Calculate Finish time of the page load in Google Chrome programatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

`Load` and `Finish` time:

[image: load and finish time]

I was able to calculate `Load` time in Google Chrome using:

```
(window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000; // seconds
```

I tried to find a value related to `Finish` time in `window.performance.timing` object but no luck. 
How can I calculate `Finish` time in the same manner as `Load` time?

Note:
I understand that [Finish time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31304442/2517622) can be dynamically changed/appended based on various reasons (e.g. user scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code for: [Chromium NetworkLogView.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js?q=maxTime%20finish&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=443)

In function `_updateSummaryBar()` from line 710 you can view the whole process of calculating the values for the summary bar. The calculation for `Finish` is the following from line 773:
`appendChunk(Common.UIString('Finish: %s', Number.secondsToString(maxTime - baseTime)));`

Whereas, `maxTime` is the end time of the last fulfilled requesd and `baseTime` is the start time of the initial request.