# Chrome developer network tab 'Finish' time is longer than 'Load' time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out how the network works in Chrome Developer Tool.
[Finish time 2.49 more than Load time 1.83](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIbOW.png)

I was just wondering why is that 'Finish' time is longer than 'Load' time? Don't they both represent response time? What's the difference between them? What effect would this have on the time to render?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website response time :Difference between "load" and "finish" ,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266960/website-response-time-difference-between-load-and-finish)

Comment: It did not answer ' What effect would this have on the time to render?'

Comment: `It seems this 'Finished' time in Chrome devtools includes the asynchronously loading(non blocking) objects/elements on the page which may continue downloading way after the onload event for page has fired.` - madballoonist in the linked answer