# Why finish (time) is increasing continously in my PHP/JAVASCRIPT website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a social networking website with PHP, MySQL, Javascript, JQUERY, and AJAX. I have setInterval and setTimeout function to show messages, friend requests etc every second with ajax. But I see that it is sending a response every second and finish time to increase continuously. Will it affect my server performance?

Please see the snapshot -

[image: Inspect website shows increasing finish time continuously]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: post effort and CODE, pictures are not enough. Right now we can only give opinions which are off topic at SO

Comment: That time is simply the difference between the time the page started to load and the last request made. So you can load a page that loads within 500 milliseconds, does nothing else (no request), and 10 minutes later fire off a `fetch()` request and that time would then read 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **finish time** logs all on-going requests even after the page has loaded (e.g. AJAX). So whenever you click a button that brings new data in the website, the finish time is extended.

If you want to monitor the initial page load time, use the **load time** just to the right.
Here is a comparison between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31304442/2026428

Comment: So it means it won't overload the server?